# Why is my while loop function only returning '1'?

Tags: c++, while-loop, return, boolean, do-while

Precursor, I just started my first coding class, so forgive me if my mistake(s) is/are painfully obvious. All I need to do right now is use a programmer defined function to ask for an integer and read out an error message until the correct input is entered, then read out the correct input.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool evenint(int num1_par);//even integer declaration

int main ()
{

int num1, correctnum1;//even integer, function call variable

cout << "Enter an even integer between 2 and 12. \n";
cin >> num1;

correctnum1 = evenint(num1); //function call

cout << "You chose '" << correctnum1 << "'" <<endl;


return 0;
}

/*
Function: evenint
Parameter/Return: An even integer between 2 and 12 inclusively
Description: This function ensures the input matches parameters before 
returning its value
*/
bool evenint(int num1_par)

{
if (!(num1_par>=2 && num1_par<=12 && num1_par % 2 ==0))// integer must be 
between 2 and 12 inclusively
{
    while (!(num1_par>=2 && num1_par<=12 && num1_par % 2 ==0))
    {
            cout << "Your number is invalid, please try again. \n";
            cin >> num1_par;
    }

    return (num1_par);
}

else
{
    return (num1_par);
}

}
```

I've tried switching my if-else/while loop to just a do-while/everything else I can think of but what I have now is the closest I've gotten. When I enter an invalid integer I get the correct response, but when I enter a valid integer it prints, "You chose '1'" no matter what valid integer I input. I've tried everything I know but now I'm stumped. Any help at all would be great!

Comment: Your condition might not do what you are expecting, see [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Although for your output you functions returns a `boolean`, so anything above `0` will show us as `1` because `true` converted to a `int` is `1`.

Comment: Your method `evenint(..)` returns a `bool` value. The `int` representativ for `true` is `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns a bool which is either zero or one. Change it to int and your code will work.